# Django filter to return results that start with the entered query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have problem pertaining to the results returned from a django queryset.

I have a table `Classified` on which I perform a search operation based on the input query `q` as follows:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.get['query']
    result = Classified.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(category__icontains=q))
    return render_to_response('search.html', {'result':result}, request)
```

Now as an example say `Classified.name` contains `Amity`, `Ambulance`, `Camden`, `Cameroon`. If I type `am` as my query, according to the above filter it'll return ALL four of the previously mentioned entries.

My question here is, how do I get it to return only `Amity` and `Ambulance` as the results because that's my requirements and plus it makes my search page much more result oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly what you're doing but use istartswith rather than icontains

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith

Answer (score 1):

I think `istartswith` filter will help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-istartswith